Aggregate Dataframe by Set Number of Rows
I have a dataframe that I would like to resample by averaging based on the number of rows.
For example i'd like to aggregate by every three rows:
   A  B  C
0  3  4  5
1  5  1  4
2  4  3  5
3  1  5  5
4  3  4  5
5  5  5  5
6  5  0  2 
7  4  0  2
8  3  2  2

With the outcome being:
  A   B   C
0 4.0 2.7 4.7
1 3.0 4.7 5.0
2 4.0 0.7 2.0

I've tried permutations on:

mdf.groupby('index1')['attr'].mean()

But end up with KeyError: 'index1'

You will need a new 'index1' column that label your groups, such as '[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]'. Then you groupby this 'index1' column, and get the mean of other columns. mdf.groupby('index1')['A'].mean()

I would do it like this.
import pandas as pd

# Sample DataFrame
data = {
    'A': [3, 5, 4, 1, 3, 5, 5, 4, 3],
    'B': [4, 1, 3, 5, 4, 5, 0, 0, 2],
    'C': [5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Calculate the mean of every three consecutive rows
result = df.groupby(df.index // 3).mean()

# Print the result
print(result)

Result:
     A         B         C
0  4.0  2.666667  4.666667
1  3.0  4.666667  5.000000
2  4.0  0.666667  2.000000


Here is a solution based on pandas.DataFrame.groupby()
import pandas as pd

# create example DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": [3, 5, 4, 1, 3, 5, 5, 4, 3],
        "B": [4, 1, 3, 5, 4, 5, 0, 0, 2],
        "C": [5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2],
    }
)

# choose the number of rows to group
chunk_size: int = 3

# perform the averaging
df = df.groupby(by=df.index // chunk_size).mean()

In this solution we take advantage of the python floor division operator  //.

As @Raymond correctly mentioned in the comment, you can add a column as index and group by that index,
num_rows=3
mdf['index1']=np.arange(0, len(mdf))//num_rows
mdf=mdf.groupby('index1').mean()

